# Update THREE.TubeGeometry path on the fly

Tags: three.js

I want to know if it's possible to update the path of a THREE.tubeGeometry after it's created

The basic code is:

```
var extrudeBend = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
// Initial Vector and Final Vector
    new THREE.Vector3(-0.043019063220379364, -0.7286175255425879, 0.32197394147509184),
    new THREE.Vector3(-0.21509537768074327, -0.7286180853596855, 2.5424840106551216)]);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, transparent: false });
var segments = 40;
var radius = 0;
var radiusSegments = 18;
var closed = false;

var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudeBend, segments, radius, radiusSegments, closed);

var tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff00ff,
    wireframe: true
}));

scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

For operative reasons, I need to modify those initial and final coordinates by different ones and refresh the entire tube again on the fly.

Modify the mesh vertext is not what I want.

```
tubeMesh.geometry.vertices[0].set(geoBoxPose.position.x, geoBoxPose.position.y, geoBoxPose.position.z).multiplyScalar(6);
```

It only modifies one vertex and I want all the tube.

Deleting the tubeGeometry and create it from zero it's a lot of memory consuming, and it is a process that is referenced every little seconds, with many geometries.

Anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: You can update the points of a curve, but if you do it, you have to re-build your geometry and change it dynamically.

Comment: I'm looking for something like modifying a THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial): lineGeometry.vertices[0].x = 10; (in real time)  but with TubeGeometry.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change these parameters without re-creating the geometry. To turn those initial and final coordinates into the shape of a spline tube is a complicated mathematical procedure, which is carried out when you create the new geometry. So that step can't be skipped.

In the highly restricted case that your spline curves are all rotations of the original one, you can just rotate the mesh, which is much faster.